# How to capture image from camera without user interaction using android

Tags: android, camera

I am developing an application which will capture the image automatically and store it in SD card when the application is started. (i.e) without any user interaction after the initialization of the application. I hear that using intent we can take pictures but user interaction is necessary.So i used camera classes. But it was not working. I came across various posts but nothing seems to be useful.
Can any one give me a suggestion?

Comment: I don't know anything about android, but god I hope this isn't possible at all. The idea of an app taking picture without my content seems awfull !

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried and what didn't work. Did you read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go through through the following tutorial and it will serve your purpose. I had a similar requirement and i used this code its working nicely!

[Camera API](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html)

See section 4 using the Camera API

Comment: Thanks a lot dude.. really it helped.. :) just customized the code found in the above link.. instead of calling the function on button click i wrote the calling function under oncreate() function itself. It worked. :)

Comment: Well that's great then Please just accept the answer by ticking the Check mark on left!!

Comment: dude can u tell me how to use this code to take picture using back side camera? it takes only in front side..

Comment: Well.. I dont know exactly how to do it.. But if i get anything i will tell you..

Comment: sure i am waiting for it.. let me know when u found it..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700847/auto-capture-image-from-camera-sony-ericsson-xperia-arc-lt15i can u check this dude?