# how to take pictures from camera automatically without user interaction android

Tags: android

I am developing women's security related applications,actually i have to send location information,audio recording information and have to send some photos also.

But my intention is automatically camera should open and take 5 photos automatically without click of camera button also.

I used following snippet of code in my application , it opens camera automatically but it is not taking photos automatically.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

 fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);


 startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Checkout this : https://github.com/sandipmjadhav/CaptureImage

Comment: Thanks for giving reply ,i got response what ever i want,but here that shown image is not showing anywhere,i mean i checked that file in sdcard it is not there,because i have to send this files to some other activity also.

Comment: i searched your problem and find this [how to capture image without user interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634476/how-to-capture-image-from-camera-without-user-interaction-using-android)